# Data Recovery Via SATA to USB Cable

Tags: windows-7, data-recovery, sata

I am trying to recover the data off a hardrive from a computer that the graphics card broke on. Its an HP Pavilion Slimline. I don't remember the exact model number but the connectors for the harddrive look like [this](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c01755036-22).

I was thinking I could use [this cable](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00HJZJI84) to get the data onto another computer. My question is, since I need to power the hard drive do I leave the power cable in the computer connected and turn the computer on while my SATA cable I bought goes to another computer?

Or is there another cable that has a separate power cable so that I can do the transfer without the dead computer?

**UPDATE** Pictures and Specs

[image: hard drive]
[image: SATA connection on harddrive]
[image: SATA Data?]
[image: SATA power?]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That adapter is intended to also power the drive (via USB's power). Depending on the power requirements for the drive in question, this may not be enough.

Leaving it hooked to another machine for power will probably work, but in general it's not a good idea, and you wouldn't be able to do that with the adapter you've linked to (since it also covers the power connector).

I'd suggest that your best bet is to get a USB SATA adapter that (can) get power directly from AC.

[For Example](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01J7MWD4M):

[image]

Comment: @Techie007 Could you look at my update? I think I calculated correctly that my drive is a 360mWatt so I could use the cable I was suggesting right?

Comment: I was hoping I wouldn't need the external power but it looks like your right. Thanks for the suggestion, I will get something like that.

Answer (score 2):

The convertor you linked to has one pluig supplying both power and connecting the data lines. Assuming that the drive is low enough power to spin up and work off USB supplied power this should work.

Most laptop drives are, but if you want ot be sure get an external adaptor with its own PSU rather than one drawing power of an USB2 or USB3 port.

(IIRC max power guaranteed from USB2 is 500mWatt and from USB3 it is 900mWatt.

For comparision: I got 2 laptop drives in front of me. A WD black and a Hitachi travelstar. Power rathing for these are 100mWatt and 1007mWatt. Many USB port seem to supply more than required though, but your mileage may vary.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the info; could you look at the pictures above in my update and tell me if if it is a 360mW drive like my math tells me? If it is, it will work on USB2 even right? One other question. the SATA part on the cable I was suggesting I buy looks different from the two cables on the computer...is it the same thing?

Comment: It looks like I probably have a 3.5 right? So I should get something like I linked but the 3.5 version.

Comment: Yes. 2.5 inch drives often only use +5 volt. The 'normal sized' 3.5 inch unit also draw +12v, often for the motor which spins the platters. USB power usually is not enough for those AND the convertor would need something to generate the +12v.  Gety something with an external PSU for this. E.g. a divice as Techhni007 showed, or an external dock like this (its the one I use)  http://i.stack.imgur.com/oTJm5.png  A third alternatiove would be to mount the disk in another desktop and copy all data from there.

Comment: The only other desktop I have is old enough to only have IDE connections so that won't work:(. Ok so for an external PSU do you think this might work: http://www.ebay.com/itm/US-SATA-IDE-To-USB-2-0-Cable-Adapter-For-DVD-Drive-HDD-Drive-Hard-Disk-W-Power-/291124346972?hash=item43c85d005c:g:t~wAAOSwd4tT5Vds

Comment: Has its own PSU and should work.